# How to change button image when clicked in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When the user hovers over a button I can change the image of the button like so in XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="troubleshooting_normal" ImageSource="/Images/troubleshooting_yellow.png" />
    <ImageBrush x:Key="troubleshooting_hover" ImageSource="/Images/troubleshooting_gray.png" />

<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="buttonTroubleshooting">
        <Grid Name="button" Background="{StaticResource troubleshooting_normal}">
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="button" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource troubleshooting_hover}" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Button Name="ButtonTroubleShooting" Template="{StaticResource buttonTroubleshooting}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="155" Click="ButtonTroubleShooting_Click"/>
```

I want to add a 3rd image for when the user clicks on the button, how do I modify the above to do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add another trigger, based on the [`IsPressed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.ispressed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="button" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource troubleshooting_pressed}" />
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with starting fresh with your own template is that you're going to miss a lot of the properties that are set on the button to make it look a certain way. Instead, wouldn't bit be great if you could copy the existing button style/template and then simply override what you need? You can.

You can simply right click on your button => edit syle => edit copy and follow the prompt. This will place all of the buttons styles into the Resources section and you can override as needed. No need to start fresh.

This is what was auto generated for me and I simply went in and changed the images for the mouse over and and click.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/V.Outlook;component/Assets/images/btn_welcome_button_hover.png" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/V.Outlook;component/Assets/images/btn_welcome_button_pressed.png" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```