# Picturebox change picture after holding down mouse button and rechange after releasing mouse C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make my PictureBox change the "Button normally" picture to "Button pressed". After I held down the mouse button, PictureBox should change its image from "Button normally" to "Button pressed" and after releasing the mouse key, it should get back to "Button normally". I've uploaded my pictures down below . Thanks in advance ☺

my first image: [Button normally](https://s4.uupload.ir/files/test_voice_button_normal_a0z6.png)

My second image: [Button pressed](https://s4.uupload.ir/files/test_voice_button_pressed_huk.png)

Edit: My code:

```
'''C# 
private void pictureBox2_Up(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.test_voice_button_pressed;
        say("Hi, im Dude, your smart assistant");
//pictureBox2_Up means MouseUp and the same thing for pictureBox2_Down
    }

private void pictureBox2_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.test_voice_button_normal;
}
'''
```

Comment: Where is the code for this feat and what is the problem or question? Note that Visual Studio doesnt seem to have anything to do with the non-question

Comment: If use XAML - you need check this [How to change button image when clicked in xaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585730/how-to-change-button-image-when-clicked-in-xaml)

Comment: @Genusatplay  I'm using C#

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I edited my post so you will understand it better. Also, both pictures exist in my project resources

Comment: @Arash Do you mean using WinForms?

Comment: See related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455439/adding-a-mouse-click-eventhandler-to-a-picturebox, you need to use MouseUp and MouseDown events.

Comment: @Genusatplay Yes

Comment: @user700390 Thanks for your comment. I tried it but it won't change the picture until I click it again but I don't want it. I want it to be like: I click, picture changes to "Button pressed" then immediately goes back to "Button normally"

Comment: @Arash There could be logical error in your event handlers, can you update the question to show the code that you wrote?

Comment: You do realize that you've got your "pressed" wired up to your "mouse up"? Careful with images in Resources; Resources is a generator

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks for your comment and help but I didn't get what you mean :( Can you please explain more clearly that what I did wrong there and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: @Arash I think your logic is backwards in the event handlers compared with your explanation of the desired behavior.  Try using `test_voice_button_pressed` in the `pictureBox2_Down()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use MouseDown and MouseUp actions. Here's the code:

```
       private void pictureBox2_Up(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.test_voice_button_normal;
        say("Hi, im Dude, your smart assistant");
    }

    private void pictureBox2_Down(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.test_voice_button_pressed;
    }
```

Special thanks to @user700390 and @CaiusJard.